# Using Bloomberg API on Excel to find a stock ticker change/acquisition

Tags: bloomberg

I am wondering if there is a way in Excel, using Bloomberg API, to find if tickers have changed or acquired by other firms.

For example, given these values,

```
BOFI US (Axos Financial Inc)
EVHC US (Envision Healthcare Corp)
COOL US (PolarityTE Inc)
```

it should return

```
AX US (ticker change on 2018/10/01)
Acquired by KKR on 2018/10/11
PTE US (ticker change on 2018/09/18)
```

respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing worth doing is to find out what's the status of the security:

```
BDP("BOFI US Equity","MARKET_STATUS")
```

returns `TKCH` signifying a ticker change. Next, you probably want `EQY_FUND_TICKER` described as:

> Returns the equity ticker for the primary security of this class/line. Primary security refers to the security trading in the class/line's primary market.

Or `FUNDAMENTALS_TICKER` described as:

> Specifies the ticker to access equity fundamental data for a company.  The price data of the fundamental ticker is used to compute most financial ratios which combine market data and equity fundamental data.  If a company has several listings/tickers, Bloomberg selects the fundamental ticker based on listing dates, country of domicile, and liquidity.

To clarify, I would only use either of these 2 fields if `MARKET_STATUS` is `TKCH`.